# How to find the font file in macOS 13.3

Tags: macos, font

I can see the font Kaiti SC in font book in macOS 13.3, but now I want to find the file location and copy to another place, where should I found the file location? I have searched the `/Library/Fonts` and `/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Fonts` but could not found the file, am I missing something? I also checked the path `/System/Library/Assets` still did not found. I did not found the font detail information in font book:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The path for Downloadable font assets is `/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_Font7`

Font Book will provide the file path of a downloaded font in its Information side panel, under "Details".